# Scope of module's methods and extension of inner classes

Tags: ruby, class, object

I ran this script:

```
module Ma
  class CLogic; end

  def execute
    "Module Ma executes."
  end
end

include Ma
CLogic.execute # => "Module Ma executes."
```

It executes `Ma#execute`. I expected something like `Undefined method 'execute' for class A.`. I want to understand why. Is class `CLogic` extended by the module because of the `include`?

Comment: It'd be nice if you posted code without the line numbers (so that we can copy/paste/run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `Ma#execute`, which was included in the main environment. That brings the definition into `Object`. Since `CLogic` is an instance of `Object`, `CLogic.execute` would be callable.

Comment: You mean `CLogic.execute`, not `CLogic#execute`

Answer (score 3):

Including a module at top-level makes its instance methods available to all objects, not just `CLogic`:

```
include Ma
123.execute    #=> "Module Ma executes."
:foo.execute   #=> "Module Ma executes."
Array.execute  #=> "Module Ma executes."
CLogic.execute #=> "Module Ma executes."
```

It's basically like:

```
class Object
  include Ma
end
```